# Implementing a counter in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj, polynomial-math

I am trying to solve a polynomial evaluation problem on SML, here is the current code I have:

```
fun eval (nil, b:real) = 0.0
|       eval(x::xs, a:real) = 
let val y:real = 0.0
fun inc z:real = z+1.0;
in
   (x*Math.pow(a,(inc y))) + eval(xs,a)
end;
```

The problem with this is that it only increments y once, is there a way to have y start at 0 and keep increasing by 1 with every recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by using the concept of local function (or helper functions). Here's the code :

```
local 
 fun helper(nil,b:real,_)=0.0
       |helper(x::xt,b:real,y)=(x*(Math.pow(b,(y)))) + helper(xt,b:real,y+1.0)
 in
 fun eval(x,a:real)= helper(x,a,0.0)
end
```

I Hope this can solve your problem :)

Comment: Thanks a ton :) that's exactly what I was looking for, to keep the same arguments passed

Answer (score 0):

`y` is set to be 0 in the `let` expression inside your function, so every time you call that function it has the value 0. If you want to have a different value for `y` for different calls to the `eval` function then you should make it a parameter of that function.

Answer (score 0):

If the `xs` are supposed to be coefficients in increasing order:

```
fun eval'( nil,  a, n) = 0.0
  | eval'(x::xs, a, n) = x*Math.pow(a, n) + eval'(xs, a, n + 1.0)

fun eval(xs, a) = eval'(xs, a, 0.0)
```

Or, since `a` is actually constant across the recursion:

```
fun eval(xs, a) =
    let
        fun eval'( nil,  n) = 0.0
          | eval'(x::xs, n) = x*Math.pow(a, n) + eval'(xs, n + 1.0)
    in
        eval'(xs, 0.0)
    end
```

Or if you don't want to write the recursion youself:

```
fun eval(xs, a) = foldl (fn(x, (s, n)) => (x*Math.pow(a, n) + s, n + 1.0)) (0.0, 0.0) xs
```